# Android WorkManager network constraint retry without cancelling previous uncompleted work

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I use Android WorkManager to download file from Firebase Storage.
The code is as the following

```java
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        dowloadFile-1
        dowloadFile-2
        dowloadFile-3
        dowloadFile-4
        return Result.success();
    }
```

```java
    // Create and start an unique work.    
    // It mean there is only one work running at the time   
    public static void start(Context context) {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                // The Worker needs Network connectivity
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();
        int backoffDelay = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.sync_retry_backoff_delay);
        OneTimeWorkRequest worker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FirebaseSyncService.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, backoffDelay, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
        WorkManager
                .getInstance(context)
                .enqueueUniqueWork(SYNC_WORK_ID, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, worker);
    }
```

```java
I use getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData()  to check state of unique work
```

And the scenario are as the following

- Step-1. Connect internet then start work
- Step-2. The program completed download file-1 and file-2
  The work state now is RUNNING
- Step-3. Disconnect internet
  Work will be stopped and WorkManager will retry by adding new Work to queue
  The work state now is ENQUEUED
- Step-4. Re-connect internet

**Expected:**
After reconnecting internet, I expect the WorkManager will perform new work from beginning and the  state is RUNING again.
I want to download file-1 and file-2 again.

**Actual**
WorkManager continue previous work and resume from downloading file-3. But the state is ENQUEUED.
Even if I change ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP -> ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, the behavior is the same.

Thank you for all supports

Comment: Hi, as per your expected output, i think you must use Periodic Work Request, instead of OneTimeWorkRequest.

Comment: @Dev007 I only expect the work run one time only but retry from beginning if error occur or constrains not meet

Answer (score 1):

check these in your worker() Java file.

- For doing network call you maybe using **try catch**, if not you have to use and then **check in catch block** you have to add return **Result.Failure**. Otherwise, even if you disconnect your internet it will continuous working(doWork() function),even work state is ENQUEUED and you will see exception in log.(Not sure reason, seems to be bug...)

I'm **not faced** these issue, when i use with **Kotlin CoroutineWorker**. its happening only if i use **Worker**

> **Note** : I'll not suggest this type of coding, use **Kotlin CoroutineWorker** and **forLoop** for multiple series of file downloads. here i'm showing only for Demo
> purpose.

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        try {
            dowloadFile-1
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.Failure; // this is important.Otherwise worker not finish,even work state is ENQUEUED
        }

        try {
            dowloadFile-2
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        try {
            dowloadFile-3
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        try {
            dowloadFile-4
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        //all success
        return Result.success();
    }
```

Quick Tip, In your case - Its better to use **ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE**, and Network call in background thread(use **CoroutineWorker()**)

Comment: I use try/catch for all work, not for each download.    
And there is no exception occur. I guess the work just pending and wait for network connected.    
I see the following log: ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.    
In addition, downloading file is sync process. I use Tasks.await(item.getFile(localFile));

Comment: I found this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156808/firebase-storage-download-file-does-not-fail-when-network-unavilable

It said that the download will not trigger exception if network is disconnected

Comment: I think you can use addOnFailureListener something, instead of try catch. Did you try adding Result.FAILURE in onResultFailure listener??

Comment: even if you use onResultFailure listener, the failure will not trigger when internet is disconnect.
In addition, I want to download file sequentially. That why i use Tasks.await

Comment: then, can you try with this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state . From here, if connected true internet available. if false you have to return Result.Failure()